# I have mysql stored procedure its create successfully but give unknown error when execute

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have mysql stored procedure, it's created successfully, but throws an unknown error when executed.

This is my query:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `attendence_status`(IN `user_id` VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN

DECLARE userid VARCHAR(255); 
DECLARE currTime TIMESTAMP; 
DECLARE logout TIME;
DECLARE login TIME;
DECLARE alid BIGINT;

SELECT ae.userid,ae.created_at,al.login,al.logout,al.id FROM an_events as ae 
LEFT JOIN attendence_log as al ON ae.userid = al.userid AND DATE(ae.created_at) = al.created_date
WHERE ae.userid = user_id AND DATE(ae.created_at)= CURRENT_DATE  INTO userid,currTime,login,logout,alid;

IF login IS NOT NULL AND logout IS NOT NULL THEN
    INSERT INTO attendence_log(userid,created_date,login,logout) VALUES(userid,DATE(currTime),MAX(TIME(currTime)),null);

ELSEIF login IS NOT NULL AND logout IS NULL AND HOUR(TIMEDIFF( MIN(TIME(currTime)),MAX(TIME(currTime)))) > 1
THEN
    UPDATE attendence_log SET logout = MAX(TIME(currTime)) WHERE id=alid;
ELSE
INSERT INTO attendence_log VALUES(null,1,DATE(CURRENT_TIME),MIN(TIME(CURRENT_TIME)),null);
END IF;


END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Please help me out ... Thank you in advance

Comment: When debugging procedures run the statements individually to see what breaks in this case I doubt the select..into please review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html

Comment: You could improve this question by adding sample data for events and attendance log as text to the question.

Comment: Apart from the select'..into being syntactically incorrect and the incorrect(?)/inconsistant use of al.userid in the select you cannot use aggregation functions in this way in the insert statements or if statements and you cannot stuff a result set into variables- If you can explain what you are trying to do here someone may be able to suggest a solution. Until you provide sample data and expected outcomes as text in the question I'm out.

Comment: I hv to table an_events and attendance_log . an_events have 3 column 1.id 2.userid 3. created_at . it will fill by fingerprint log data. Now i want to manipulate this data to attendance_log table. attendance_log table have 1.id 2.userid,3.created_date,4.login,5.logout . Here login will fill by an_events min(TIME(created_at) but when login and logout filed is not null for same day and same user it will be min(TIME(created_at) after first sift logout time.2.logout filed will fill by when login  column already have data ,logout fill is null and min 1 hour gap btwen  login and max(TIME(created_at)